# ASP.NET Core 5 Web API, POST return CreatedAtAction error

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .NET version 5.0.100-preview.8.20417.9 . What is wrong at here:

```cs
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(TrustedPerson), new { id = item.Id }, TrustedPerson(item));
```

Model

```cs
using System;

#nullable disable

namespace shadow.Models
{
    public partial class TrustedPerson
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string AliasName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber1 { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber3 { get; set; }
        public int? RelationshipId { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public int? AvatarId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
    }
}
```

File `TrustedPersonController`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using shadow.Data;
using shadow.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace shadow.Controllers
{

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TrustedPersonController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db; 

        public TrustedPersonController(ApplicationDbContext context) : base()
        {
            this._db = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UserId = id của người dùng chính.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="UserId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("all")]
        public ActionResult GetAllTrustedPersons(string UserId)
        {
            var list = from trustedPerson in _db.TrustedPeople
                       join userTrustedPerson in _db.UserTrustedPeople on trustedPerson.Id equals userTrustedPerson.TrustedPersonId
                       // join user in db.Users on User.Identity.Id 
                       where userTrustedPerson.UserId == UserId
                       select trustedPerson;
            return Ok(list.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TrustedPerson>> AddTrustedPersons(TrustedPerson trustedPerson)
        {
            var item = new TrustedPerson
            {
                Fullname = trustedPerson.Fullname,
                About = trustedPerson.About,
                AliasName = trustedPerson.AliasName,
                AvatarId = trustedPerson.AvatarId,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                Email = trustedPerson.Email,
                PhoneNumber1 = trustedPerson.PhoneNumber1,
                PhoneNumber2 = trustedPerson.PhoneNumber2,
                PhoneNumber3 = trustedPerson.PhoneNumber3,
                RelationshipId = trustedPerson.RelationshipId
            };
            _db.TrustedPeople.Add(item);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(TrustedPerson), new { id = item.Id }, TrustedPerson(item));
        }
    }

}
```

Error

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5002
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\shadow_backend
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10400]
      Sensitive data logging is enabled. Log entries and exception messages may include sensitive application data, this mode should only be enabled during development.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]
      No type was specified for the decimal column 'Id' on entity type 'Topic'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values using 'HasColumnType()' or specify a ValueConverter.
warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]
      No type was specified for the decimal column 'PublisherId' on entity type 'Topic'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values using 'HasColumnType()' or specify a ValueConverter.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

D:\shadow_backend\bin\Debug\net5.0\shadow.exe (process 13440) exited with code -1.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

[image: ame]

Comment: The error appears to be reasonable: I don't see an _action_ named `TrustedPerson` in your question.

Comment: I see something like this at here https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/92293546-a3093a80-ef4e-11ea-8532-765abf80ff53.png  @KirkLarkin please explain for me about it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#prevent-over-posting

Comment: It's the first parameter for `CreatedAtAction` that's the issue: `nameof(TrustedPerson)`. In the docs version, it's `nameof(GetTodoItem)`, where [`GetTodoItem`](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-web-api/samples/3.0/TodoApiDTO/Controllers/TodoItemsController.cs#L32) is the name of an action defined in the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

As `Kirk Larkin` says,the first parameter is action name,you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_CreatedAtAction_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_).Here is a demo worked:

```
public class Item { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
        [Route("TrustedPerson")]
        public IActionResult TrustedPerson(int id)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [Route("TestCreatedAtAction")]
        public IActionResult TestCreatedAtAction() {
            Item item = new Item { Id = 1 };
            return CreatedAtAction("TrustedPerson", new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }
```

or you can use `return CreatedAtAction(nameof(TrustedPerson), new { id = item.Id }, item);`